# Why doesn't homebrew apache start at startup?

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew

I’m trying to figure out why my apache doesn’t start at startup… (I would like for it to).

**My OS:** OSX Mojave

**Impressions I’m under:** that I’m running homebrew’s apache

Upon a fresh boot…

If I hit http://localhost in a browser I get

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost.
```

Fire up terminal…

```
$brew services list
```

returns

```
httpd started bigpimpin /Users/bigpimpin/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist

php   started bigpimpin /Users/bigpimpin/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
```

(That first line makes me think httpd is running and I should be able to hit localhost).

```
$which -a apachectl
```

returns

```
/usr/local/bin/apachectl
/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

then

```
$apachectl configtest
```

returns

```
Syntax OK
```

then

```
$sudo apachectl -V
```

returns (among other things)

```
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf"
```

(Isn’t this brew’s httpd.conf?)

There's a brew command (which I forget) that I already ran that is supposed to run httpd at startup.

Once I run

```
$sudo apachectl start
```

everything is jake. So it’s a low-priority question, but one I would like to solve and understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with Homebrew NGINX.
Running the brew services command with `sudo` solved the problem for me.

It appears that the Homebrew web-server packages require `sudo` to start | stop | restart.

Try running:

`sudo brew services start apache2`